# BeautifulSoup4 Get "li a" with no text inside li

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need help getting some specific anchors from a website. The website has this structure

```html
<li>
  This has a link
  <a href="#">1st link</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">2nd link</a>
</li>
<li>
  This also has a link
  <a href="#">1st link</a>
</li>
```

I want to get only the anchors that have no text inside de `li`.
What is the easiest way to achieve this with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can analyze the elements of `soup.contents` to determine if only `soup` objects exist:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(s, 'html.parser')
results = [i for i in d.find_all('li') if all(not isinstance(c, str) or c == '\n' for c in i.contents)]
```

Output:

```
[<li>
  <a href="#">2nd link</a>
</li>]
```